# Copy content from one Azure OS Disk to another

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azureportal

I crashed my VM on Azure and wasn't able to restart it, so I loaded a backup. Problem is, that the Backup created a new disk with the data. I need to get the content of the Disk created by my Backup to my original OS Disk though. Is there a way I can wipe the old OS Disk and Copy the Data from the new one to it?

I tried to find a way to copy them but I haven't found one that works, because they are not in a Storage Account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copy content from one Azure OS Disk to another

In order to copy the data from backup disk to original `OS` disk, follow the below steps.

1. Create a `Temporary Azure Virtual Machine`.
2. Delete original `VM` with excluding `OS Disk`

[image]

5. Attach the old `OS disk` and backup data disk (**the one you already created from backup data**) to temporary `Azure Virtual Machine` as a data disk, like below.

[image]

6. Login to `Temporary Azure Virtual Machine` and mount backup disk and original `OS` disk

Open **run** > type: **diskmgmt.msc** > **Disk Management** > **Select  Disk**  and make it online.

[image]

[image]

7. Now, copy the data from backup disk to original vm os disk using below command

```
robocopy G:\   F:\  /E /Z /LOG:C:\RobocopyLog.txt
```

If you want to copy specific folders, command is below.

```
robocopy G:\data  F:\  /E /Z /LOG:C:\RobocopyLog.txt
```

If you want, you can wipe the original `OS` disk before copying the data from the backup.

[image]